# Where are the best places to post Drupal 7 RFP?

Tags: 7, theming, community-official-site

Do you have any thought on the best places to post an RFP for Drupal 7 development and theme work?

I have posted on drupal.org and groups.drupal.org but someone mentioned odesk, but I wasn't sure if that would be fruitful or just overkill.

Answer (score 1):

drupal.org reaches a wide audience, and is a good venue.  That said, please be aware that widely distributing an RFP can be harmful to your project.  Many of the best shops don't respond to RFPs.  Advomatic has [published an interesting presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/Advomatic/put-the-rfp-down) on this topic.

Comment: Hey, unfortunately I watched that video by Advomatic after we had committed to this process. Still it was not my decision and it might have turned out the same either way. Anyway, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is the [paid services forum](http://drupal.org/paid-services) on drupal.org and there is also the #drupal-consultants channel on chat.freenode.net, wher you can find consultants to discuss the project in real time.